# How do I properly format this Regex search in R? It works fine in the online tester

Tags: regex, r, parsing

In R, I have a column of data in a data-frame, and each element looks something like this:

`Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Marinilabiaceae`

What I want is the section after the last semicolon, and I've been trying to use 'sub' and also duplicating the existing column and create a new one with just the endings kept. In essence, I want this (the genus):

```
Marinilabiaceae
```

A snippet of the code looks like this:

```
mydata$new_column<- sub("([\\s\\S]*;)", "", mydata$old_column)
```

In this situation, I am using `\\` rather than `\` because of R's escape sequences. The `sub` replaces the parts I don't want and updates it to the new column. I've tested the Regex several times in places such as this: http://regex101.com/r/kS7fD8/1

However, I'm still struggling because the results are very bizarre. Now my new column is populated with the organism's domain rather than the genus: `Bacteria`.

How do I resolve this? Are there any good easy-to-understand resources for learning more about R's Regex formats?

Comment: specific for r with examples https://github.com/raredd/regex

Comment: also, since regex isn't the end all, be all, `tail(strsplit(tmp, split = ';')[[1]], 1)` would work

Comment: +1 to for the link to regex101. Bookmarked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your simple string,

```
string <- "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Marinilabiaceae"
```

You can remove everything up to the last semicolon with `"^(.*);"` in your call to `sub`

```
> sub("^(.*);", "", string)
# [1] "Marinilabiaceae"
```

You can also use `strsplit` with `tail`

```
> tail(strsplit(string, ";")[[1]], 1)
# [1] "Marinilabiaceae"
```

Your regular expression, `([\\s\\S]*;)` wouldn't work primarily because `\\s` matches any space characters, and your string does not contain any spaces.  I think it worked in the regex101 site because that regex tester defaults to  `pcre (php)` (see "Flavor" in top-left corner), and  R regex syntax is slightly different. R requires extra backslash escape characters in many situations. For reference, [this R text processing wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing) has come in handy for me many times before.

Comment: This worked great! Would you mind explaining why my old syntax did so poorly?

Comment: I added the short and sweet explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Make it Greedy and get the matched group from desired index.

```
       (.*);(.*)
             ^^^------- Marinilabiaceae
```

Here is [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT4eX9/4)

Or to get the first word use *Non-Greedy* way

```
             (.*?);(.*)
Bacteria -----^^^
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT4eX9/5)

Answer (score 1):

To extract everything after the last ; to the end of the line you can use:

```
[^;]*?$
```